# Maven: PL/SQL script with sql-maven-plugin throws error PLS-00103

Tags: sql, jdbc, plsql, maven-2, sql-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use the sql-maven-plugin to execute a PL/SQL script on an Oracle 11 database. Although the script is valid PL/SQL (as far as I can tell), the execution gives me a PLS-00103 error:

The SQL script: (drop_all_tables.sql)

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE';
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

And my plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-schema</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
                        <username>${jdbc.username}</username>
                        <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <srcFiles>
                            <srcFile>src/main/resources/sql/drop_all_tables.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And this is the output from the Maven execution:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute:  BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE';
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ORA-06550: line 2, column 43:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge
```

Comment: The code output in your Maven error message doesn't quite match the code you posted at the top of your thread.

Comment: Oh true sorry, I edited out the table name to be generic, forgot to do it in the error output - done now :)

Comment: the point is, the code you're actually *executing* is different from what *you're showing us*.  How do you expect us to interpret a syntax error if you don't show us the actual code?

Comment: No, no, the code I'm executing produces the same error - I modified it now to show the correct output error (the previous one was the same error, but on a different table)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess the plugin is splitting the sql script by semicolons and trying to execute each part independently. The first statement would be

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MY_TABLE';
```

Which is incomplete as far as oracle is concerned. The plugin does have two configuration parameters to change this behaviour, [delimiter](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#delimiter) and [delimiterType](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#delimiterType). By changing the configuration like below and separating your `BEGIN` blocks by a `/` on a line by itself you should be able to execute this script.

```
<configuration>
    <delimiter>/</delimiter>
    <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, that may work, and I'll certainly check it out, but I've found an alternate way of doing what I wanted without having to use PL/SQL. I added <onError>continue</onError> to the configuration section of my Maven plugin, and the SQL is now the much simpler DROP TABLE MY_TABLE;

Comment: I would add that as an answer, but cannot add an answer to my own question for now as I'm a newbie here :)

Comment: The answer (maven configuration) works, and the script is correct