# PL/SQL script in sql-maven-plugin throws invalid SQL statement

Tags: oracle, sql-maven-plugin

I am trying to update my materialized view using sql-maven-plugin but its says

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Query :

```
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''M_CUSTOMER'')';
end;
```

Even after spending hours and hours on this, i am not able to figure out the issue. Thanks in advance.

The queries I want to execute are not simple DDL queries but DBMS_MVIEW package or other packages. Other answers have the solution for DDL but not for package.

Project structure

[image]

Comment: You should show us the actual Java code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The project don't have any java code. Just the POM and SQL files. I'll update the directory structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: PL/SQL script with sql-maven-plugin throws error PLS-00103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580165/maven-pl-sql-script-with-sql-maven-plugin-throws-error-pls-00103)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not enough or too many levels of indirection here :-)

You either want:

```
begin
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('M_CUSTOMER');
end;
```

or

```
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''M_CUSTOMER''); end;';
end;
```

with the former being the most likely.

Comment: Agree with this. Also, doesn't OP need to set delimiter to `row` [according to documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/faq.html)?

Comment: Agreed.  Maven ain't my thing

Comment: Thanks @ConnorMcDonald :)